# Is there a way I can run all my SoapUI test suites at once, if they are under different projects?

Tags: automated-tests, soapui

On my SoapUI Workspace, I have several Projects.

Each one of these may contain one or more test suites, with several test cases

It is quite time consuming to expand each project, then open up the test suite, run it, open up the next etc. I do this for testing locally, then for testing again a test box

Is there a way I can run through all tests in my SoapUI workspace in one click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just write a script to run all the tests using the command line.

For example if you have 2 Projects, Project1 and Project2, which each contain 2 test suites you could write a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./testrunner.sh -sUnitTesting -f Project1-soapui-project.xml
./testrunner.sh -sUnitTesting2 -f Project1-soapui-project.xml
./testrunner.sh -sotherTests -f Project2-soapui-project.xml
./testrunner.sh -sotherTests2 -f Project2-soapui-project.xml
```

Comment: Is that testrunner script available under windows?

Comment: Yes, here is the link to the example for using the test runner on the soapui site.  http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html
In the example you can see that launching the test runner just runs the testrunner script in soapui.  You can copy the command at the top of the output and just run it on the command line.

Let me know if you run into trouble and I can help you out some more.

Comment: It stops after first execution. Do you know why?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't found a way yet in ver. 3.5.1.

You can save a little bit of time by doing the following:

Double click on the PROJECT
Click on the "Test Suites" Tab
Click the RUN button.

This will run all suites within the project.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (CMD) use:

```
@echo off
set SOAPUI_HOME=C:\DevTools\soapui\SoapUI-Pro-5.0.0
call %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\testrunner.bat -sUnitTesting -f Project1-soapui-project.xml
call %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\testrunner.bat -sUnitTesting2 -f Project1-soapui-project.xml
call %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\testrunner.bat -sotherTests -f Project2-soapui-project.xml
call %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\testrunner.bat -sotherTests2 -f Project2-soapui-project.xml
```